# Android Map programming

Tags: android

Actually i am developing a Map browser app in Android. I have a .dat file contains map information with a File format like this,

```
struct point{
    int x,
        int y;
};
```

How can i read this .dat file using this format and copy the values into x and y?

Comment: ".dat" is not a commonly accepted format AFAIK.  You'll need to be more specific as to how the data is formatted and structured.  Also, this is faaar too broad of a questions for SO as it is currently worded.

Comment: Do you want to draw this points OVER map or you want to create a map with this data?

Comment: Yes, I want to create a map using this dat file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To draw a map, you need to extend [View class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) and implement methods such as [onMeasure(int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure%28int,%20int%29) and [onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29). Then inside onDraw you can draw your mapping elements directly with [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) methods such as drawArc, drawCircle, drawLine, drawOval, drawPath, drawPoint, drawRect, drawText and so on.
To get a clue look at this class (for example) in [mapsforge](http://code.google.com/searchframe#8SMNiUpcFlI/trunk/mapsforge/src/org/mapsforge/android/map/CanvasRenderer.java&q=Canvas%20package%3amapsforge%5C.googlecode%5C.com&ct=rc&cd=2&sq=).

Answer (score 1):

If you mean offline map browser (Tiles stored locally in phones SD card) you have several options:

1- Use osmdroid map viewer ([code.google.com/p/osmdroid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid)). This library supports a range of formats for offline mode and also is able to connect to some online map tile providers(like [openstreetmap](http://www.openstreetmap.org)).
To create offline tiles for this library you can use [Mobile Atlas Creator](http://mobac.sourceforge.net).

2- Use [mapsforge](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge). This library generates map tiles based on the data (renders map tiles dynamically).

Comment: Thanks Ali. I will try this and will get back to you.

Comment: Hi Ali, I have updated my question. please check this. I also checked osmdroid, but couldnt find anything usefull.